# Image not showing

Tags: php

I have used this code for accessing image from database to web page. But after debugging there is no image in image tag.

This code prints the correct path....but fails to return correct image in image tag...

```
echo $_SESSION['user_image'];
```

How do I get the image in image tag?
plz help me.

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {

    $_SESSION['user_id']    = $row['user_id'];
    $_SESSION['user_name']  = $row['user_name'];
    $_SESSION['user_level'] = $row['user_level'];
    //$_SESSION['user_image'] = $row['image'];
    $image=$row['image'];


    $user_image= trim('C:/xampp/htdocs/source/img/' . $image);
    //$user_image = imagecreatefromstring($user_image);
    $_SESSION['user_image']=$user_image;
    echo $_SESSION['user_image'];
    }
    echo "<img src='".$row['image']."'>";
    echo 'Welcome, <img src= "'.$_SESSION['user_image'].'" alt="" width="50"     
    height="40" /> ' . $_SESSION['user_name'] . '. <br /><a href="index.php">Proceed to  
    the forum overview</a>.';
```

Comment: Can you show the output of `echo $_SESSION['user_image']`?

Comment: on which browser your testing your code ? if you are using chrome then can you please inspect element and see what path do you get on img tag

Comment: try to give the relative path from your web server's root dir,  i.e  `$user_image = trim('/source/img/'.$image);`

Answer (score 0):

You are using the local path in the server.

```
'C:/xampp/htdocs/source/img/' . $image
```

Should be

```
'/source/img/' . $image
```